# Azure blob : Understanding different options in BlobListingDetails Enum

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I found the options in [BlobListingDetailsEnum](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.bloblistingdetails?view=azure-dotnet) very confusing. Following are the options:

All - List all available committed blobs, uncommitted blobs, snapshots and deleted blobs and return all metadata and copy status for those blobs.

Copy - Include copy properties in the listing.

Deleted - Include deleted blobs in the listing.

Metadata - Retrieve blob metadata for each blob returned in the listing.

None - List only committed blobs, and do not return blob metadata.

Snapshots - List committed blobs and blob snapshots.

UncommittedBlobs - List committed and uncommitted blobs.

My confusion comes from the following:
seems {commited, uncommited, deleted} are describing the state of a blob, while {metadata, copy} is a section of a data in the return value, and {snapshot} is a form of presenting the result, why these options show up in the same enum? is this understanding correct? I could not find good documentation explaining these terms.

Comment: Hi Yituo, do you have any more concerns about the Enum options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct, these items are mixed.

As per our experience, it's very useful for users to filter out the unwanted items by using different values like snapshots, deleted etc. Another good point is that, the code would be much more faster if you filter out the unwanted items by using proper enum value.